# How to navigate from fragment to activity when class Extends YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: android

Cannot get my floating button to successfully navgiate from an Activity page to a fragment page. I believe it is because the activity page extends YoutubeBaseActivity and not AppCompat so the getSupportFragmentManager() method is not found.

Can someone please help me work around this?

```
public class ActivityDetailsActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {


@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ActivitiesFragment fragment = new ActivitiesFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `YouTubeBaseActivity` - use a normal `AppCompatActivity` and `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`.

Comment: Why shouldnt I be using YoutubeBaseActivity?

Comment: `YouTubeBaseActivity` extends `Activity` and therefore has no support for Support Library Fragments (the only Fragments you should be using) or any of the AppCompat theming you need.

Comment: I tried this and it gives an error AppCompactActivity clashes with onStart(), Im assuming because your answer involves multiple inheritences which java does not support?

Comment: The only thing your Activity should be extending is `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager%28%29) instead `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Tried this, throws an error saying "Cannot resolve method add (int, ActivitiesFramgnet)"